# Sync image files from network with mariadb-Database

Tags: database, synchronization, file-handling, python-3.x, path

i have as a mechanical engineering student in my practice semester to create a database that includes about 100k+ paths to images in our network. Every, lets say week, i have to synchronize all changes in the network with my DB. So i have to delete Data from the DB if someone deleted a Image in the network or i have to insert new data to my DB.

My problem is, that it needs to long to compare the whole network with my DB, cause of that many paths.

I have spotted few real-time solutions for my problem like `watchdog, FindFirstChangeNotification, ReadDirectoryChanges API`. But i have the order, to look for something like `Rsync` or `FreeFileSync`, so a solution that already exist. I looked at both, but i am really not sure that they could help me with my problem.

I use Python to get all needed metadata from images and insert it to a mariadb-Database on a Windows Computer.

Do you have any ideas that i can follow or is there someone outside that had the same problem?

Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Who gave the order to use rsync or FreeFileSync? They apparently didn't understand the task at hand (or I didn't understand it...) As far as I can see, your task isn't to synchronize file contents but to maintain an up-to-date database of image files on network file servers, correct? That's not something a file synchronisaton tool does.

Comment: My chef gave me the order (we both are very inexperienced in DB). He thinks we are not the first with this problem and there must be a existing solution, so he called me to search something like Rsync and i found FreeFileSync. Thank you for answering Hans-Martin Mosner, i think you understood my task correctly. In my opinion, i have to create a own solution with something like ```watchdog``` to maintain my database up-to-date. But is there a other library, that not have to run in a endless loop?

Comment: I'm always a little uncertain where the border line between this site and stackoverflow.com should be drawn, but I feel asking for a specific problem architecture instead of general aspects of software architecture might fit better there. Note that tool recommendations are off-topic here, and this site as well as the others on the stack exchange network has some criteria for checking what questions are on-topic. You might start at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic which also includes a list of possible alternative StackExchange sites.

Comment: I was uncertain too. I first started to write my problem on stackoverflow, but then i became the information about this side and thought it would fit better to this side. 

Never mind. Thank you for your answers. I will check the link you sent to me, before i will reask there.